# Sensitivity analysis of parameter on eigenvalues of predator-prey model

Tags: differential-equations, list-manipulation, eigenvalues, ecology

I am trying to do a sensitivity analysis of the parameter `g` on the eigenvalues of this simple predator-prey Lotka Volterra model. I know that this code is entirely wrong, but I am very unfamiliar with Mathematica syntax and struggle with loops. I am new to Mathematica, so detailed explanations are appreciated! Thank you!

```
Table[Print[eigs[i]], {i, 0, 5, 1},
 
 par = {g -> i, k -> 200, c -> 0.1, e -> 0.4, d -> 2};
 
 dr = g*r*(1 - r/k) - c*n*r;
 dn = e*c*n*r - n*d;
 
 solall = 
  FullSimplify[
    Solve[{(dr /. par) == 0 && r > 0, (dn /. par) == 0 && n > 0}, {r, 
      n}, Reals]] [[1]];
 
 one = D[dr, r] /. par /. solall;
 two = D[dr, n] /. par /. solall;
 three = D[dn, r] /. par /. solall;
 four = D[dn, n] /. par /. solall;
 
 jacobian = {{one, two}, {three, four}};
 MatrixForm[jacobian];
 
 eigs[i] = N[Eigenvalues[jacobian]];
 ]
```

Edit 1: My actual model is a more complicated 4-species and does not have a symbolic solution, hence why I need to do this loop to find the eigenvalues, since I cannot create the Jacobian from the symbolic interior equilibrium. I am trying to learn/understand loops in Mathematica with this simpler scenario, because I normally do sensitivity analysis in R.

Edit 2: Here is my actual model, and I think I figured it out/I think this code is correct (i.e. this gives me the eigenvalues as a function of parameter `g`)

```
Table[
 
 par = {k -> 200, c1 -> 0.15, c2 -> 0.15, c3 -> 0.05, e1 -> 0.9, 
   e2 -> 0.1, e3 -> 0.2, d1 -> 0.1, d2 -> 0.1, d3 -> 0.2, u1 -> 0.1, 
   u2 -> 0.1};
 
 dr = g*r*(1 - r/k) - c1*n*r - c2*r*p;
 dn = e1*c1*r*n - c3*n*z - n*d1;
 dp = e2*c2*r*p - p*d2 - u1*n*p + u2*r*z; 
 dz = e3*c3*n*z - z*d3 - u2*r*z + u1*n*p; 
 
 solall = 
  FullSimplify[
    Solve[{(dr /. par) == 0 && r > 0, (dn /. par) == 0 && 
       n > 0, (dp /. par) == 0 && p > 0, (dz /. par) == 0 && 
       z > 0}, {r, n, p, z}, Reals]] [[1]];
 
 one = D[dr, r] /. par /. solall;
 two = D[dr, n] /. par /. solall;
 three = D[dr, p] /. par /. solall;
 four = D[dr, z] /. par /. solall;
 five = D[dn, r] /. par /. solall;
 six = D[dn, n] /. par /. solall;
 seven = D[dn, p] /. par /. solall;
 eight = D[dn, z] /. par /. solall;
 nine = D[dp, r] /. par /. solall;
 ten = D[dp, n] /. par /. solall;
 eleven = D[dp, p] /. par /. solall;
 twelve = D[dp, z] /. par /. solall;
 thirteen = D[dz, r] /. par /. solall;
 fourteen = D[dz, n] /. par /. solall;
 fifteen = D[dz, p] /. par /. solall;
 sixteen = D[dz, z] /. par /. solall;
 
 jacobian = {{one, two, three, four}, {five, six, seven, 
    eight}, {nine, ten, eleven, twelve}, {thirteen, fourteen, 
    fifteen, sixteen}};
 MatrixForm[jacobian];
 
 eigs = N[Max[Re[Eigenvalues[jacobian]]]],
 
 {g, 5, 20, 1}
 ]
```

Comment: Just for working with these types of equations, you might have some use out of [`NondimensionalizationTransform`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NondimensionalizationTransform.html).

Comment: If you look at the documentation for [`D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/D.html) under `Details and Options` you will see that your Jacobian can be calculated directly with `jacobian = D[{dr, dn, dp, dz}, {{r, n, p, z}}] /. par /. solall`

Answer (score 9):

Here's a solution using [my EcoEvo package](https://github.com/cklausme/ecoevo), which is designed for just this kind of problem.  First, install the package (only need to do this once):

```
PacletInstall["EcoEvo", "Site" -> "http://raw.githubusercontent.com/cklausme/EcoEvo/master"]
```

Then load the package and set the model:

```
<< EcoEvo`

SetModel[{
  Pop[r] -> {Equation :> g*r[t]*(1 - r[t]/k) - c*n[t]*r[t]},
  Pop[n] -> {Equation :> e*c*n[t]*r[t] - n[t]*d}
}]
```

Solve for equilibria:

```
eq = SolveEcoEq[]
(* {{r -> 0, n -> 0}, {r -> k, n -> 0}, {r -> d/(c e), n -> (g (-d + c e k))/(c^2 e k)}} *)
```

Looks like you're interested in the third `eq`.

Finally, set the parameter values and loop over `g`:

```
k = 200; c = 0.1; e = 0.4; d = 2;

Table[EcoEigenvalues[eq[[3]]], {g, 0, 5}]
(* {{0, 0}, {-0.125 + 1.21835 I, -0.125 - 1.21835 I},
    {-0.25 + 1.71391 I, -0.25 - 1.71391 I}, {-0.375 + 2.08791 I, -0.375 - 2.08791 I},
    {-0.5 + 2.39792 I, -0.5 - 2.39792 I}, {-0.625 + 2.66634 I, -0.625 - 2.66634 I}} *)
```

The equilibrium is stable with damped oscillations unless `g=0`.

To verify, you can set `g=5` and simulate the dynamics and look at the phase plane:

```
g = 5;
sol = EcoSim[{r -> k, n -> 0.01}, 10];
PlotDynamics[sol]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
PlotEcoPhasePlane[{r, 0, k}, {n, 0, 80}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

*Updated model (X2)*

Oops, I found a few typos in my previous version, that actually change the results.  Sorry about that!  It should be corrected here.  Also, since `p` and `z` are both part of the same population, it's nice to incorporate that structure (let's you calculate invasion criteria).

Here's how you could do your full model:

```
SetModel[{
  Pop[r] -> {Equation :> g*r[t]*(1 - r[t]/k) - c1*n[t]*r[t] - c2*r[t]*p[t]},
  Pop[n] -> {Equation :> e1*c1*n[t]*r[t] - n[t]*d1},
  Pop[igp] -> {
    Component[p] -> {Equation :> e2*c2*r[t]*p[t] - p[t]*d2 - u1*n[t]*p[t] + u2*r[t]*z[t]},
    Component[z] -> {Equation :> e3*c3*n[t]*z[t] - z[t]*d3 - u2*r[t]*z[t] + u1*n[t]*p[t]}
  }
}]

k = 200; c1 = 0.15; c2 = 0.15; c3 = 0.05; e1 = 0.9; e2 = 0.1; e3 = 0.2;
d1 = 0.1; d2 = 0.1; d3 = 0.2; u1 = 0.1; u2 = 0.1;

Table[
 eq = SolveEcoEq[];
 Max@Re@EcoEigenvalues[eq[[-1]]]
, {g, 5, 20}]
(* {-0.0254927, -0.000919339, 0.0112321, 0.0185581, 0.0234753, 0.02701,
0.0296758, 0.0317591, 0.0334325, 0.0348064, 0.0359548, 0.0369291, 
0.0377662, 0.0384931, 0.0391304, 0.0396936} *)
```

So looks like a bifurcation around `g=6`.  We can simulate to verify:

```
g = 6;
sol = EcoSim[{r -> 0.7, n -> 20, p -> 26, z -> 750}, 1000];
PlotDynamics[sol]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
g = 7;
sol = EcoSim[{r -> 0.7, n -> 20, p -> 26, z -> 750}, 1000];
PlotDynamics[sol]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you, Chris! My problem though, is that my actual model is more complicated and there is no symbolic solution to it. Normally, I construct the Jacobian matrix in Mathematica and bring it over to R for sensitivity analysis. But now, I need to do the entire thing in a loop in Mathematica. This code just keeps running forever. My model is: `dr = g*r*(1 - r/k) - c1*n*r - c2*r*p;
dn = e1*c1*r*n - c3*n*z - n*d1;
dp = e2*c2*r*p - p*d2 - u1*n*p + u2*r*z; 
dz = e3*c3*n*z - z*d3 - u2*r*z + u1*n*p;`

Comment: Could you edit your question to add these equations and also give parameter values?

Comment: Sure, just added it in. I think I figured it out. I was not familiar with how to loop through the parameter values, but the code I added works now.

Comment: BTW, what's the full model about?

Comment: @ChrisK have you had anyone use this for spin glasses/thermal magnetics models? I remember learning that one can model these systems as predator prey systems! Can you please clarify this for me?

Comment: @CATrevillian I'm used to physicists invading ecology; haven't seen the other way around!  But I never made it past E&M, so no idea.

Comment: Chris, thank you for your updated response! I am happy to have discovered your package in this process. My model is a spin off IGP, where the IG predator is treated as two separate species, one that feeds on the basal resource and the other that feeds on the primary consumer, u1 and u2 being the switching parameters between the two morphs.

Comment: If you're interested, it's based off an experimental protist microcosm system I work with in the lab. Blepharisma is the IG predator. It has two distinct trophic polymorphisms - microstome, which feeds just on bacteria, and macrostome, which feeds on smaller protists including the microstomes!

Comment: Hello, Clara! I'm interested in the local bifurcation analysis of your model.